# Calculated in-document hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, formula, openoffice-calc

I would like to create a calculated hyperlink that will target a cell within the same document. Insert > Hyperlink allows this option and uses the string #Sheet1!A1, for the Cell A1 on Sheet1, for example.

Is there a way to express this feature as a formula such that it can create the hyperlink based on the result of a calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's the [HYPERLINK() function](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_HYPERLINK_function):

> `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#Sheet1!",T(E2)),"Test")`

NB: when working with other language settings then "English (USA)", OOo might require other argument separators (for example: with "German (Germany)", semicolons instead of commas are required).

Split on multiple lines for readability:

```
=HYPERLINK(
    CONCATENATE(
        "#Sheet1!",
        T(E2)
    ),
    "Test"
)
```

It will insert a hyperlink, with the target depending on the content of the cell `E2`. Using the [T() function](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_T_function), the Sheet could be set dynamically, too. In my example, `E2` could have the value of "A1", resulting in a hyperlink pointing to `#Sheet1!A1`.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of a hyperlink with target sheet, target cell and hyperlink text set dynamically:

[image: dynamically created hyperlink]

using this formula:

> `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#",T(D1),"!",T(D2)),T(D3))`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much tohuwawohu!